# Parse file path to logfile argument in solve method from pyomo's SolveryFactory wtih cplex solver

Tags: python, cplex, pyomo

I´m using pyomo 5.7.3 with cplex 12.9.

I´m calling solve method from pyomo's SolverFactory and logging to file `'model.log'` using the code bellow (which works fine).

```
optimizer = SolverFactory('cplex')

results = optimizer.solve(
        model,
        warmstart = True,
        tee = True,
        logfile = "cplex.log",
        )
```

But if i change logfile to `'./runs/cplex.log'` an error is raised:

> ValueError: Unallowed character (/) found in CPLEX log file path/name.
> For portability reasons, only [a-zA-Z0-9 ~:.-_] are allowed.

Is there a way for me to parse into the logfile argment the path to the folder './runs' without raising the error?

Also, is it possible to use a logger from logging package and output cplex log to this logger?

Thank you,

---

EDIT: Solved in a naive way (code bellow). Is there a better way?

```
initial_dir = os.getcwd()

os.chdir(run_dir) #changing to log dir in order to avoid providing unallowed characters to lgofile argument in solve method

results = optimizer.solve(
    model,
    warmstart = True,
    tee = True,
    logfile = f'{model_name}_cplex_log.log',
    )

os.chdir(initial_dir) # returning to former directory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using pyomo 5.7.3, the way ought to be:

```
import os
log_folder = os.path.join(".","runs")
from pyomo.common.tempfiles import TempfileManager
TempfileManager.tempdir = log_folder
```

Don't forget to create the folder if it does not exist.

PS: I wrote a little wrapper for the solver function in Pyomo which does this automatically, as well as post-processes all your variables after solve if you want to [check it out](https://github.com/judejeh/PyomoSolverWrapper), although the log folder is named "_log" in my case, log files grouped by folders based on model name, and then named by date and time.